# HISTTIMEFORMAT plain doesn't work

Tags: bash

Setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in `bash` to get timestamps in the history report just isn't working:

```
> fgrep HISTTIMEFORMAT ~/.bashrc
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%m-%d-%y %T '
> bash
> history | tail -20
181  git status
182  man git-push
183  history | tail 
184  help history
185  export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "
186  history | tail 
187  export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m-%d-%y %T"
188  history | tail 
189  HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m-%d-%y %T"
190  history | tail 
191  echo $HISTTIMEFORMAT
192  man 3 strftime
193  set | fgrep HIST
194  HISTTIMEFORMAT='%m-%d-%y %T '
195  history | tail 
196  export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%m-%d-%y %T '
197  history | tail 
198  bash
199  export HISTTIMEFORMAT
200  history |tail -2
> set | fgrep HIST
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HISTFILE=/home/eewanco/.bash_history
HISTFILESIZE=200
HISTSIZE=200
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%m-%d-%y %T '
> set | fgrep BASH 
BASH=/bin/bash
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.1.2(1)-release'
```

I vaguely recall having similar trouble and successfully getting this to work at a previous company with a special trick but I can't remember what it was. The history file is logging timestamps correctly, in fact I was able to get the information I wanted with a `date -d @` command, but I want this solved for future usage. I've seen logs of people doing precisely what I did and it works for them. It works fine on my Samsung tablet.

Comment: surely you don't have `history` aliased to something else, like `fc -l`? what does `alias history` say?

Comment: or better, `type history`?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you. Gotta love IT for mucking with things behind the scenes. Even if I knew it was aliased, though, it's not obvious based on the help for `fc` that `fc -l` omits the timestamps. 

Is there a particular advantage to `fc -l -$HISTSIZE` over the default `history` command? What might possess IT to substitute the former for the latter?

Comment: `fc` is more portable -- if you share you home dir between multiple systems via nfs, it may be nice to have some stock aliases that work everywhere (I eg. have `alias %=fg` -- but I made it conditional on the shell used, unlike your IT department ;-)).

Answer (score 2):

As @mosvy suggested, my IT department had `history` aliased to `fc -l -$HISTSIZE`, which doesn't show timestamps. Running `\history` shows me the timestamps.